# Unable to store data in database after unmarshalling a xml resource

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, spring-mvc, jaxb

I have two entities `ValCurs` and `Valute` which with I'm mapping a remote `xml` resource. The data are stored in the database only for `Valute` entity.

*Here are my entities:*

**`ValCurs` entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "valCurs")
@XmlRootElement(name="ValCurs")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ValCurs {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@XmlAttribute(name = "Date")
private String date;

@XmlElement(name = "Valute")
private ArrayList<Valute> allValutes;


public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public ArrayList<Valute> getAllValutes() {
    return allValutes;
}

public void setAllValutes(ArrayList<Valute> allValutes) {
    this.allValutes = allValutes;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

}

**`Valute` entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "valute")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Valute {

@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "char_code")
@XmlElement(name = "CharCode")
private String charCode;

@Column(name = "nominal")
@XmlElement(name = "Nominal")
private Integer nominal;

@Column(name = "value")
@XmlElement(name = "Value")
private Float value;

@Column(name = "name")
@XmlElement(name = "Name")
private String name;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCharCode() {
    return charCode;
}

public void setCharCode(String charCode) {
    this.charCode = charCode;
}

public Integer getNominal() {
    return nominal;
}

public void setNominal(Integer nominal) {
    this.nominal = nominal;
}

public Float getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(Float value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

I am unmarshalling in this way:

```
        URL url = new URL(BNM);
        InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());

        // Converting a XML to java object with JAXB, (UnMarshalling).
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ValCurs.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        ValCurs valCurs = (ValCurs) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(is);

        // Extracting the list of Valutes from the root xml
        ArrayList<Valute> listOfValutes = valCurs.getAllValutes();

        // Storing data into database
        for (Valute valute : listOfValutes) {
            valuteService.add(valute);
        }

        valCursService.add(valCurs);
```

Whe I run the code it throws me an: `could not serialize; nested exception`
which I can understand why (it cannot serialize: `private ArrayList<Valute> allValutes;` in one cell of a table).

I need to obtain the `id` and `date` from `ValCurs` but I cannot achieve that (`valCursService.add(valCurs);` throws exception so I cannot to store data in database.)

*My question is this:* how can I store the data from `ValCurs` in a table, (maybe I'm missing something in Jaxb annotation technique, I'm really new in persistence in java).

**P.S.** Xml that I'm parsing is this:

```
<ValCurs Date="20.04.2015" name="Official exchange rate">
<Valute ID="47">
<NumCode>978</NumCode>
<CharCode>EUR</CharCode>
<Nominal>1</Nominal>
<Name>Euro</Name>
<Value>19.3441</Value>
</Valute>
<Valute ID="44">
<NumCode>840</NumCode>
<CharCode>USD</CharCode>
<Nominal>1</Nominal>
<Name>US Dollar</Name>
<Value>18.0558</Value>
</Valute>
</ValCurs>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have oneToMany relation between ValCurls and value and you need to inform JPA to store this relation as such.

The missing bit is the @OneToMany annotation on the collection:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "valCurs")
@XmlRootElement(name="ValCurs")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ValCurs {    
...    
   @XmlElement(name = "Valute")
   @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
   private List<Valute> allValutes; //you should use List rather than ArrayList
```

The cascade=CascadeType.ALL roughly means that if you insert new ValCurs than its Valutes will be inserted as well and that if you remove ValCurs than the corresponding Valutes will be also removed. orphanRemoval = true has the effect that if you remove a Valuete from the allValutes list it will be also removed from the table.

Now, to have the relationship represented in the DB there must be link betweenthe ValCurs and its Valute. Simplest way is an "parent" column in Valute table containing id of the ValCurs. You achieve it by adding joincolumn annotatins:

```
   @XmlElement(name = "Valute")
   @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
   @JoinColumn(name ="VALCURS_ID")
   private List<Valute> allValutes; //you should use List rather than
```

You can also have a join table instead (google how to do it).

I don't know your valCursService implementation, but with the cascade setup you need to persist only ValCurs and the related valutes will be saved automatically.

so in JPA:

```
EntityManager em = ...;
em.persist(valCurs); //no need for valuteService.add(valute);
```

in hibernate:

```
Session session = ...;
session.save(valCurs);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but anyway now tomcat is telling me that: **SEVERE: Error listenerStart**. after changing to `@OneToMany` I cannot read the XML. My service is a simple service to store data in db: `public void add(ValCurs valCurs) { valCursDao.save(valCurs); }` where `ValCursDao extends JpaRepository<ValCurs, Long>{}`

Comment: post the whole error, it cannot be xml related, rather the DB mapping is wrong.

Comment: `SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Apr 20, 2015 5:08:11 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
[2015-04-20 05:08:11,654] Artifact exchange-rate-app-api:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.`

Comment: I received this error earlier when I came up with the `List`, but when I changed to `ArrayList` it happily compiled...(that was strange for me). That's why I used `ArrayList`.

Comment: the actuall error is earlier in the log or not in this one log file.

Comment: List is not a problem for Jaxb.

Comment: This was above of earlier error: `Apr 20, 2015 5:08:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Apr 20, 2015 5:08:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal`

Comment: Look for the error that actually makes sense. Are you using an IDE to run (Netbeens, eclipse?). You can change it back to ArrayList but it should not matter.

Comment: I'm using Intellij Idea 14.1, and after changing back ( just now) it throws me `SEVERE: Error listenerStart`  but after changing back to `ArrayList` it works fine (but not storing `ValCurs` data in db )

Comment: after changing back ( just now) it throws me .. but after changing back to ArrayList it works, so does it work or not with ArrayList. I don't know Intelli, but you may have to tabs with server output one for the applicatin one for the server. The error would be then in the second tab. The listener start is top level, somewhere below it is actuall cause.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work either it is `ArrayList` or either it is `List`.

Comment: Does not work or you have an exception. Two different things. The solution works for persisting to DB. As for the error before you actually find the one that causes it is difficult to help. My guess, is you already have tables structure but without the join column in it, so the persistence cannot start.

Comment: I deleted all tables from database, added your annotations, but in log file it says `SEVERE: Error listenerStart` and the tables hasn't been created. I created the the domain model to parse that xml resource. If I remove your annotations the tables are created but when I call `valCursService.add(valCurs);` then it throws an serialization exception. But with `@OneToMany` it doesn't even pass the creation of tables.

Comment: Did you used the @JoinColumn(name ="VALCURS_ID") as well? THERE IS THE persistence error before your Error listenerStart, which includes information why the tables could not be created and what is wrong. As it says the details are in server log. If you cannot see it in your IDE, pack the app to war and deployed it manually to the server. Then check the window you are running the tomcat from and the logs in tomcat/log

Comment: You are right it is a persistence problem (and I don't know how to handle), I have an error:  `Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.exchange.admin.models.ValCurs.allValutes references an unknown entity: java.util.List`

Comment: And this one: `Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:924)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76)`

Comment: you kept the generic type List<Valute> as in your example code? cause you should not see such exception. What is your java target? Maybe it is something old like 1.5 or some very,very old hibernate. You can add @OneToMany(targetEntity=Valute.class, ....) to inform what is the type but it should not be normally needed.

Comment: Now with the List is everything ok, but I'm facing an exception: `HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.exchange.admin.models.Valute; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.exchange.admin.models.Valute`

Comment: remove the for() valuteService.add(valute); use only valCursService.add(valCurs) with cascade=Cascate.ALL inside OneToMany